# Debug and execute current c# method in JetBrains Rider

Tags: c#, jetbrains-ide, rider, testdriven.net

I have recently moved to Rider (JetBrains), and looking for a tool/plugin similar to [TestDriven.net](https://testdriven.net)

This allowed me to debug the method at cursor without having to setup unit tests or other projects to call the selected method.

Any alternatives would be appreciated. I am currently using NUnit and applying TestFixture and Test attributes to my functions which then show up in Unit Tests tab but this isnt ideal

Answer (score 2):

For static methods that is available already.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Run_Debug_Configuration_dotNet_Static_Method.html